# C - How do I run a program in the background using exec?

Tags: c, exec

There is a program I can run on terminal like so: `./program &`

But I'm trying to do it using execvp and it isn't working:

```
            pid = fork();
            char *argv[3] = {"./program", "&",  NULL};

            if ( pid == 0 ) {
                execvp( argv[0], argv );
            }
            else{
                wait(NULL);
            }
```

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Plese **edit your question** to motivate it and explain what you really want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `"&"` you have in the `argv` array isn't going to do what you want, and may be the source of your problem here. That's a place for program arguments, and `&` is a shell command, not a program argument. Remove it since the `./program` will run in a separate process anyway since you've forked.

Comment: I would  say that `&` is a shell *syntax*; it is not a command by itself.

Answer (score 4):

As [answered by Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46860201/841108), the ending `&` is a shell syntax (it is technically not a shell command) related to [job control](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control.html).

In your question, it is unclear why you need it. You could just not use that  `"&"`, and your code should work. Read also about [background processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_process), about [terminal emulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator), about [process groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group). Read the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/).

BTW, you could instead of `wait`  use [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) and specify the pid. You generally need some waiting (e.g. `wait`, `waitpid`, [wait4(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait4.2.html), etc ....) to avoid having [zombie processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process). You may want to handle the `SIGCHLD` signal, but read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) & [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).

Perhaps you want to use the [daemon(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) function. See also [setsid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsid.2.html), [setpgrp(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setpgrp.2.html),  and [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html). Otherwise, you probably should call `wait`  much later in your program. You might want to redirect (using [dup2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html)), perhaps to `/dev/null`, to some other [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)-ed file descriptor, to some [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), etc..., the *stdin* (and/or *stdout* and *stderr*) of your child process. You may also want to multiplex input or output using [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html).

Your code should [handle the failure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17707740/841108) of [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) (when it gives -1), perhaps using [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) in such case. You also should handle failure of [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html).

In some limited and specific particular cases, you could want to [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) a `sh`, [nohup(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nohup.1.html), `batch`, `at`, or `bash` but you generally don't need that.

<sup>(without understanding your motivations, and why you want to run something in the [background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_process), we can't help you more)</sup>